# How to classify the singularities of $sin(\frac{1}{sin\pi z})$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to classify the singularities of $sin(\frac{1}{sin\pi z})$. I think it should be essential singularities but I do not know how to prove it. To prove that it is not a pole nor a removable singularity I need to look at its limit at n, but how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, the limit of your expression as $z \to n$ along the real line (this is a real variable limit) clearly doesn't exist (even in the extended sense) and so each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is an essential singularity.